# Extract words from a file, then list files along with line number that contain those words

Tags: python, bash

I have a file called Strings.h, that I use to localize an app I have. I want to search through all of my class files, and find out if and where I am using each string, and output the classes and line numbers for each string.

My thought is to use Python, but maybe that's the wrong tool for the job. Also, I have a basic algorithm, but I worry it will take too long to run. Can you write this script to do what I want, or even just suggest a better algorithm?

Strings.h looks like this:

```
#import "NonLocalizedStrings.h"

#pragma mark Coordinate Behavior Strings
#define LATITUDE_WORD NSLocalizedString(@"Latitude", @"used in coordinate behaviors")
#define LONGITUDE_WORD NSLocalizedString(@"Longitude", @"used in coordinate behaviors")
#define DEGREES_WORD NSLocalizedString(@"Degrees", @"used in coordinate behaviors")
#define MINUTES_WORD NSLocalizedString(@"Minutes", @"Used in coordiante behaviors")
#define SECONDS_WORD NSLocalizedString(@"Seconds", @"Used in DMSBehavior.m")

...
```

The script should take each line that starts with #define, and then make a list of the word that appears after #define (e.g.) LATITUDE_WORD

The pseudocode might be:

```
file = strings.h
for line in file:
  extract word after #define
  search_words.push(word) 

print search_words
[LATITUDE_WORD, LONGITUDE_WORD, DEGREES_WORD, MINUTES_WORD, SECONDS WORD]
```

After I have the list of words, my pseudocode is something like:

```
found_words = {}
for word in words:
   found_words[word] = []

for file in files:
  for line in file:
    for word in search_words:
      if line contains word:
        found_words[word].push((filename, linenumber))   

print found_words
```

So, found words would look something like:

```
 {
   LATITUDE_WORD: [
                    (foo.m, 42),
                    (bar.m, 132) 
                  ],
   LONGITUDE_WORD: [
                    (baz.m, 22),
                    (bim.m, 112) 
                  ],

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this [in bash] ?

```
$ pattern="\\<($(grep '^#define ' Strings.h | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//'))\\>"
$ find project_dir -iname '*.m' -exec egrep -Hno "${pattern}" {} + > matches
```

Output:

```
project_dir/bar.m:132:LATITUDE_WORD
project_dir/baz.m:22:LONGITUDE_WORD
project_dir/bim.m:112:LONGITUDE_WORD
project_dir/foo.m:42:LATITUDE_WORD
```

**EDIT**: I've altered the code above to redirect it's output to a file `matches`, so we can use that to show words that are never found:

```
for word in $(grep '^#define ' Strings.h | cut -d' ' -f2)
do
    if ! cut -d':' -f3 matches | grep -q "${word}"
    then
        echo "${word}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can you possibly update this to search a directory, recursively, and also output any of the words that are never found? I think this is probably the best solution, and I'm sorry to update the requirements!

Comment: It already searches `project_dir` recursively for files matching `*.m`. Outputting words that are never found is trickier, given the way it works.

Comment: Okay, edited to output never-found words as well. Took me a while to think that through ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have one more question. When I run the find command, I get this error: egrep: empty (sub)expression

Comment: Are you using BSD `grep` rather than GNU `grep`, by any chance - maybe because you're on Mac OS X? If so, I've made an edit to the `pattern="...` line in my answer that might help (and in any event, produces a cleaner regex).

Comment: Thanks, wish I could buy you a beer. I am on a mac, and your script works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

So, it looks like you've got the right idea.  Here are some advantages and disadvantages to what you've got.

**Advantages:**

- If you use Python, your pseudocode translates almost line for line
  directly to your script.
- You can learn a little bit more about Python (great skill to have for things like this).

**Disadvantages:**

- Python will run a bit slower than some of the other bash-based solutions that have been posted (which is a problem if you have a lot of files to search).
- Your Python script will be a little bit longer than these other solutions, but you can be a little bit more flexible with your output as well.

**Answer:**
Because I'm familiar with Python, and that's what you asked for originally, here's a bit more code you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# List the files you want to search here
search_files = []
word_file = open('<FILE_PATH_HERE>', 'r')

# Allows for sorted output later.
words = []

#Contains all found instances.
inst_dict = {}

for line in word_file:
    if line[0:7] == "#define":
        w = line[7:].split()[0]
        words.append(w)
        inst_dict[w] = []

for file_name in search_files:
    file_obj = open(file_name, 'r')
    line_num = 0
    for line in file_obj:
        for w in words:
            if w in line:
                inst_dict[w].append((file_name,line_num))
        line_num += 1

# Do whatever you want with 'words' and 'inst_dict'
words.sort()
for w in words:
    string = w + ":\n"
    for inst in inst_dict[w]:
        string += "\tFile: " + inst[0] + "\n"
        string += "\tLine: " + inst[1] + "\n"
    print string
```

I haven't tested the search portion of the code, so use 'as is' at your own risk.  Good luck, and feel free to ask questions or augment the code as you need.  Your request was pretty simple and has lots of solutions, so I'd rather you understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `awk` and `globstar` (the latter requires Bash 4). I think there can be further improvements but consider this a draft of sorts.

```
shopt -s globstar

awk 'NR==FNR { if ($0 ~ /^#define/) found[$2]=""; next; } 
     {
       for (word in found){
         if ($0 ~ word) 
           found[word]=found[word] "\t" FILENAME ":" FNR "\n";
       } 
     }
     END { for (word in found) print word ":\n" found[word]}
    ' Strings.h **/*.m
```

Using the snippet of Strings.h you posted, here's the sort of output I get (with some testfiles I made up)

```
LATITUDE_WORD:
    lala1.m, 2
    lala3.m, 1

DEGREES_WORD:
    lala2.m, 5

SECONDS_WORD:

MINUTES_WORD:
    lala3.m, 3

LONGITUDE_WORD:
    lala3.m, 2
```

p/s: Haven't tested this with `globstar` since the bash I'm using right now is v3 (pfff!)

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
grep -oP '^#define\s+\K\S+' strings.h
```

If your `grep` lack the `-P` option :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /^#define\s+\K\S+/' strings.h
```

Comment: When I try the grep command, grep lists usage rules: usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python program. It can probably be reduced and made simpler, but it works.

```
import re
l=filecontent.split('\n')
for item in l:
  if item.startswith("#define"):
    print re.findall("#define .+? ", item)[0].split(' ')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Assuming $files constains a list of your files
word_list=( $(grep '^#define' "${files[@]}" | awk '{ print $2 }') )
```